# Windows 8.1 VM takes all Memory and CPU

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I got some issues when running my Windows VM on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, it seems that the VM is taking all the memory and CPUs and the system was slowed down really bad.

My Current System is, 
`Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 
 Memory: 15.6 GiB
 Processor i7-5600U @ 2.6GHz x 4`


My VM system is, 
`Windows 8.1 Pro
 Installed Memory: 8.00 GB
 System type : 64-bit`


When running the VM, my system performance looks like the following graph,
[image]

And the configuration of my VM is, 
[image]

My machine runs really slow and the fan is much noisy than normal. By the way, my Windows is idling without running any program.

Does anyone have the similar issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Whether the Virtualization is enabled within the BIOS?

Comment: @pa4080 I updated my post, and I think the Virtualization is enabled.

Comment: @pa4080 yes. it is enabled for sure.

Comment: In the guest OS settings, set the memory to 2048 and the CPU's = 2. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema, you made a good point. I changed to 2CPUs and 4G, the performance for the Host OS is better. But the windows VM is much slower. I mean 4G 2CPU should be running well right?

Comment: @HaipengSu 4G is probably still excessive. I'd go with 2048 and see how that works. The guest OS should work pretty good. I've made a quickie answer... maybe you can accept it if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered [dual-booting?](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=askubuntu+dual+boot+windows+8) VM performance will never compete with bare metal and this approach would have the added benefit of allowing full utilization of your systems resources when you are forced to run Windows.

Comment: @ElderGeek Thank you for the advice. However, Dual-boot is not an option for me since I need both systems running at the same time.

Comment: Windows is a resource hog, whereas 16.04 is pretty lean by comparison (I actually have 16.04 running on a cheesy netbook with only 2GB and an Atom CPU). Be that as it may, you get to choose how to allocate the resources. I notice you have 6.4 GB swap in use along with 15.3 GB  of your main memory. When you have more going on than you have resources to support you can expect things to slow down.

Comment: I am not understanding about the Swap memory. When I stop the VM, the system is only using 2-4GB. and once I started the VM, it seems the VM takes all CPUs and memory. I guess one of the reasons is I set 4 cpus for the VM which is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

In the guest OS settings, by setting CPU=4 you've committed all of the CPU resources in your computer to the guest VM. Host operation will slow to a crawl. Generally speaking, you shouldn't commit more than half of the number of physical CPUs to a guest VM.

In the guest OS System settings, set the memory to 2048 and the CPU's = 2.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you considered expanding on this to explain how these settings are changed or perhaps referring to [an answer that does?](https://askubuntu.com/a/728082/225694)

Comment: 2GB is too slow for me. I will stick to 4G now, my main system is running better when setting 2 CPUs for the VM.  I will accept your answer later in case someone has a similar symptom with a better solution.  Thank you.

Comment: I think the CPUs configuration matters. Thank you so much.

Comment: @HaipengSu glad it's working for you now. Thanks for the update!